# Linq Expressions for Indexer Properties

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework, linq-expressions

```
var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Employee), "t");    
MemberExpression member = Expression.Property(param, "EmployeeName");
var value = Convert.ChangeType(filterProperty.Value, member.Type);
ConstantExpression constant = Expression.Constant(value);
var body = Expression.Or(leftExpr, Expression.Equal(member, constant));
```

I can easily get the expressions for normal properties, but ***How I can get expression for indexer properties?***

In `Employee` class I have two indexers.

```
    class Employee
    {
       public string EmployeeName {get;set;}

       public string this[EmployeeTypes empType]
       {
          get
           {
             return GetEmployee(empType);
           }
       }

       public string this[int empNum]
       {
          get
           {
             return GetEmployee(empNum);
           }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `Item` as property name:

```
var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Employee), "t");
MemberExpression member = Expression.Property(param, "EmployeeName");
var body = Expression.Property(param, "Item", Expression.Constant(10));
var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<Employee, string>>(body, param);
var compiled = lambda.Compile();
```

gives you the same what could be done by

```
Func<Employee, string> compiled = t => t[10];
```

Comment: Exception: Instance property 'Item(Int32)' is not defined for type 'PEWQ.TA.Component.Employee'

Comment: It means your `Employee` class does not looks like you showed us. I tested it with your sample `Employee` class and it works.

Comment: This will work for most indexers, but not for all of them. The indexer property is usually called `Item`, but it doesn't have to. For example, [the indexer for `string` is called `Chars`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.chars.aspx).